# Get API Gateway's IP address in Lambda Function (by Python)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function that has an API Gateway trigger and wonder if there are any method to get the API's IP address?

I already get the request Address by event & context like 'xxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-xxxx-1.amazonaws.com'. by following code:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    result = str(event.get('params').get('header').get('Host'))
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

the requester's ip is here:

event['requestContext']['identity']['sourceIp']

Comment: You need to include inline code span so the code is readable & verifiable. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how & why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer